# Displaying Cards on an imageView

Tags: android, xml, imageview

Hello i am trying to display cards on an image view one slightly overlaying the other. I was thinking of using padding, but i am not sure how to use it. Thanks. Here is how i display my cards.

```
while(bl.dealerIterator.hasNext() == true)
{
    dealerCards.setImageResource(bl.dealerIterator.next().cardImage());     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `AbsoluteLayout` and offset every `ImageView` by some amount!

Answer (score 0):

**Never use AbsoluteLayout!**

You could do offscreen compositing of the individual card images into a single offscreen Bitmap that you display in your ImageView.